# Convert EC2 instance to VMware workstation

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, vmware-workstation, vmware-tools

How can I export one windows instance (with active directory, SQL, SharePoint) from amazon (EC2) to my local environment, and be able run it on a local VMware workstation?

I have used the VMware vCenter converter to do this and I am able to get the virtual machine using the following instructions: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1018015

However, when I try to run it on VMware workstation, the machine doesn't load and I get the blue screen.

Repairing doesn't fix it, and I think the problem is Active Directory.

Any ideas? It is possible to take a clone directly from amazon volumes/virtual disk? Maybe using a different tool?

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is using the converter like you did. You might want to try install vmware tools before you run the converter on it. This was the machine will have the correct drivers when it comes up on VMWare Workstation

Why do you think it is related to AD? I'd think it has something to do with the virtual hardware that changed.